# A formula for counting points on a elliptic curve over a finite field

Tags: elliptic-curves

Let $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is an elliptic curve, #$E(\mathbb{F}_p)=p+1-a$ and  $x^2-ax+p=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$.

Now I found the following formula here https://joeylitalien.github.io/assets/elliptic-curves.pdf  (Theorem 3.3)

# $ E(\mathbb{F}_{p^2})=p^2+a-(\alpha^2+\beta^2)$ but it doesn't work in problems.

What is wrong?

Comment: Careful with your URLs! Anyway, not everything on the internet is true...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|E(\Bbb F_p)|=p+1-\alpha-\beta$ with $\alpha\beta=p$ then
$$|E(\Bbb F_{p^n})|=p^n+1-\alpha^n-\beta^n.$$
Here,
$$|E(\Bbb F_{p^2})|=p^2+1-\alpha^2-\beta^2=p^2+1-a^2+2p$$